# Converting PHP foreach loop to ColdFusion

Tags: php, coldfusion

I have the PHP Code which is using a foreach loop to loop over and create a query. I am trying to convert that into ColdFusion, but am getting lost. Can someone show the way how that can be done?

```
if ($deps) {
    $num = count($deps); 
    $i = 0;
    $addon = " AND (";
    foreach ($deps as $dep) {
        $addon .= " DEPARTMENT_ID='{$dep['dep']}'".($num != ++$i ? ' OR': '');
    }
    $addon .= ")";
} else {
    // Has been assigned no departments, so they can't see any tickets
    $addon = " AND (DEPARTMENT_ID='-1')";
}
```

Comment: What's the full query suppose to look like?

Comment: What's confusing you? Where's the CFML code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: In coldfusion 10 there is also a nice ArrayEach function: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArrayEach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the PHP translated *directly* to CFML, that is: *with as few changes as required* to make it compile and run:

```
<cfscript>
    if (isDefined('$deps')) {
        $num = ArrayLen($deps);
        $i = 0;
        $addon = " AND (";
        for ($dep in $deps) {
            $addon &= " DEPARTMENT_ID='#$dep['dep']#'"&($num NEQ ++$i ? ' OR': '');
        }
        $addon &= ")";
    } else {
        // Has been assigned no departments, so they can't see any tickets
        $addon = " AND (DEPARTMENT_ID='-1')";
    }
</cfscript>
```

Here is an screenshot of a diff showing what has changed:

[image: diff of php and cfml code]

The changes are:

- Need [isDefined](http://cfdocs.org/isDefined) to check for non-null value.
- [ArrayLen](http://cfdocs.org/ArrayLen) instead of [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to get size of an array.
- `foreach ( Y as X )` translates to `for ( X in Y )`
- Use `&` and `&=` for concatenation, instead of `.` and `.=`
- PHP uses `{braces}` when a bracket notation var is inside a string - for a single variable it could have just been `$varname` directly and would be evaluated. In CFML you use `#hashes#` to put variable's values in a string.

Note that CF lets you use `!=` in script, but `NEQ` must be used in tag-based code (cfif/cfset).

Also note that, whilst PHP requires variables to start with a `$` sign, CFML does not care either way, so they don't strictly need to be removed (even if they are ugly noise).

---

Here is the same concept done in a simpler way:

```
<cfscript>
    if ( NOT isDefined('deps') )
        deps[1] = {dep=-1};

    addon = [];
    for ( dep in deps )
        ArrayAppend(addon," DEPARTMENT_ID='#dep.dep#'");

    addon = " AND (#ArrayToList(addon,' OR')#)";
</cfscript>
```

And here's an example of how similar code could work with cfqueryparam instead:

```
<cfscript>
    if ( isDefined('deps') )
    {
        depIds = [];

        for ( dep in deps )
            ArrayAppend(depIds,dep.dep);
    }
    else
    {
        depIds = [-1];
    }
</cfscript>
<cfquery>
    ...
    <cfif ArrayLen(depIds) >
        AND DEPARTMENT_ID IN (<cfqueryparam list value=#ArrayToList(depIds)# cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />)
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

(Proper code would of course use better variable names and appropriate scoping.)

Comment: That was a great explanation of the code you provided here

Answer (score 3):

Forget the php code.  It looks like it's looking to create something like this:

```
and (
department_id = value1
or
department_id = value1
etc
)
```

Instead, look to create something like this:

```
and departent_id in 
(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#SomeList#" list="yes">)
```

You can use conditional logic to create the SomeList variable.  It can either be something like "1,3,5" or "-1" depending on the ColdFusion equivalent of the $deps variable.

Comment: so basically that eachloop is creating a list right,

Comment: Not necessarily.  You may already have one.  Where does the $deps variable come from in your php app?

Answer (score 1):

I like Dans solution but here is your code translated to CF:

```
<cfif IsDefined('deps')>
   <cfset num = ArrayLen(deps)>
   <cfset i = 0>
   <cfset addon = " AND (">

   <cfloop array="#deps#" index="dep">
      <cfset addon &= " DEPARTMENT_ID='#dep#'" & num NEQ ++i ? ' OR': ''>
   </cfloop>
       <cfset addon &= ")">
<cfelse>
    <cfset addon &= " AND (DEPARTMENT_ID='-1')">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the trailing bracket in the right spot?

Comment: Solved @osekmedia, Thanks for the code too. Also i prefer using StructKeyExists rather than isDefned, i hate it

Comment: This code doesn't actually work, and is a bad way to write it anyway - what Dan suggests is better.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Without seeing the rest of the program code this was the best translation I could do. I agree StructKeyExists is a better option but I was unsure of the scope of the variable. I could optimize this code but this was exactly what the question asked for. I simply converted the code that was presented.

Comment: @Peter, As you can see I recommended Dans code before presenting my solution. I simply converted the code exactly as presented.

Comment: Doesn't work either means an error or unexpected results.  If it means an error in this case, what is the error message?

Comment: @Dan, fixed the closing bracket. Thank you!

Comment: I think we are all agreed that `<cfqueryparam list>` is much simpler. However, IMO it is still very useful to see a translation as it demonstrates the correlation between some of the php and CF functions. Once you understand the code, it becomes clear the original PHP code is inefficient. Then you can throw it all out the window and use the cfqueryparam instead, secure in the knowledge that you have not lost anything but inefficient code ;-)

Comment: I disagree with "exactly as presented" - see the answer I just added for this being done. As for whats wrong with it, well you've already spotted and corrected the `!=` and the incorrectly placed closing paren - but you've still missed that `$dep` is a struct, and more importantly you need to maintain the parentheses around the ternary operator to prevent the condition becoming the entire of `" DEPARTMENT_ID='#dep#'" & num NEQ ++i`.

Comment: (Edit) @PeterBoughton - I do not think it is a perfect translation, however IMO it is a good start at least for the OP. (There were no similar posts at the time). Encouraging them to learn *something* about php syntax, rather than just providing the answer, will help with their future translations, so they do not post blanket questions like this one (hint, hint). ie Teach a man to fish. That is not a slam on anyone that did provide an answer, just my $0.02